# Why won't Visual Studio recognize any keywords and why doesn't intellisense work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I just took over a project running(being hosted) on a Windows Server 2008 and the project is a Visual Studio 2010 Project. I open up the project only to find that all the text is black. For example, all the using keywords are black instead of the VS blue they should be. Very Strange.. Come to find out you can't even "Go To Definition" and no intellisense or auto-complete is working.

I'm thinking this is missing some sort of plug-in or update. I Google'd and found NADA.

Any Ideas?

P.S. I don't post questions often so constructive criticisms are very welcome.

EDIT: I am running Visual Studio as an Administrator

Comment: Here's a list of quick checks you can do to try and fix your problem: 1\ Restart VS and or your computer. 2\ Reset visual studio's settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings) 3\ Repair visual studio through the control panel. On an other note, is this happening only for files within this project? Does it happens for all new projects or only a specific kind of file?

Comment: Thanks @EtienneMaheu I will check that out and let you know!

Comment: are you sure you opened a project or solution and not a source file?

Comment: Some aspects of VS don't work right unless you are running as administrator. I ran into this exact issue until I realized that.

Also Plutonix suggestion is a serious consideration if you are editing an ASPX, CSHTML, or VBHTML file directly. To get full intelligence you will need to have the project file or the solution file.

Comment: @Plutonix I am sure, I opened the solution.

Comment: @Brian It was already running as admin. I will edit my initial comment to include that. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes deleting the suo file in your solution folder helps. Should be in the same place as sln file.

Answer (score 1):

Your Visual Studio is opening the CS files in the normal text editor component, hence it shows no colored syntax, no IntelliSense and other things.

Right click a CS file in your solution explorer and select "Open with ...".

A new window pops up. Select CSharp-Editor, click on the "As Default" button and then click on the "OK" button.

[image: Select Editor Preview]

Comment: That has to be it! @modiX but let me ask you. If CSharp-Editor isn't there, where can I get it? I haven't Google'd yet, I'm about to. Thought I'd ask anyway!

Comment: Yeah so, 10 minutes of solid googling and I'm not even close. Where and how can I download the CSharp-Editor @modiX

Comment: @CodeFlava Unfortunately you cannot install the CSharp-Editor, because it's a part of the IDE itself. If it's missing, this is strange, please uninstall and install your Visual Studio, again.

Comment: Hey sorry, got tied up with some things... trying it tonight

Comment: Barely even remember this issue... I never got the chance to try it